# How do I see current status of runtime options of less utility?

Tags: linux, less, pager

Less takes runtime options from `LESS` environment variable + system-wide `lesskey` file + `$HOME/.less` file + command line arguments + runtime commands invoked by user.

#### Use case

After toggling some options while running less for some file I would like to see current status of all options.  I would like to capture the state of all options when I am fully satisfied with less behavior and save them in `LESS` environment variable for setting default options for a user.

#### Sources of information I have already investigated

Quite surprisingly, I failed to find answer in

- [man documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html)
- [Less official FAQ](http://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html)
- first two google search pages, including the search scoped to superuser.com site.